# Blender Python - exporting bone matrices for animation relative to parent

Tags: python, export, armature, bones

I am making a homegrown 3d engine for my projects.
So far, I am able to export:

- mesh
- materials
- Node hierarchy

Each node in my engine has it own mesh(optional), material(optional) and a PARENT-RELATIVE-TRANSFORMATION-MATRIX

While rendering, each node passes its own matrix down to each children.
This matrix get multiplied with the child node's transformation matrix and gets passed down further.

This is working fine for static meshes with node hierarchy.
However it is not working for Blender bones(I have a plugin for 3ds max also, and my engine is able to render bones correctly. So I think the issue is not on renderer side.)

I am getting all weird matrices for bone animations.
Here is my script where I save the animation data for bones.

```
for node in nodes:
    if node.pose_bone:
        (start_frame, end_frame) = (0, 100)
        animation = Animation(len(animations), int(start_frame), int(end_frame))
        animations.append(animation)
        node.animationIndex = animation.index

        print("==>>")
        for f in range(int(start_frame), int(end_frame) + 1):
            bpy.context.scene.frame_set(f)
            bpy.context.scene.update()

            if node.pose_bone.parent is None:
                bone_matrix = node.pose_bone.matrix_basis
            else:
                parent_matrix = node.pose_bone.parent.matrix_basis
                bone_matrix = node.pose_bone.matrix_basis
                bone_matrix = parent_matrix.inverted() * bone_matrix

            m = bone_matrix

            animation.translates.append( m.to_translation() )
            animation.rotates.append( m.to_quaternion() )
            animation.scales.append( m.to_scale() )
```

Please help me to get correct pose matrices for bones.
In my engine these need to be relative to their parent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you export bones relative to parent?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/how-do-you-export-bones-relative-to-parent)

Comment: I had already tried the solution as in that link. But it wont work for me.

Comment: 'wont work' because you couldn't get it to work or because there are specific requirements for your code? If the latter please add additional information to your question. Thanks :)

Comment: "because there are specific requirements for your code?"
yes.
I need to get data for animation. while the linked question is for bind pose, if I understood correctly.
I was not able to figure out a solution from the linked question.
It would be great help, if anybody can rephrase information from the linked question to solve my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a couple of days of frustration, I have been able to get skeletal animation working fine.

Here are the details:
1] Bind pose is obtained from bone.matrix_local

```
bone_matrix = bone.matrix_local
if pose_bone.parent:
    bone_matrix = bone.matrix_local.inverted() *   bone.matrix_local
```

2] Inverse bindpose also is obtained from bone.matrix_local. But this time it is not relative to parent bone.

```
offset_matrix = bone.matrix_local.copy().inverted()
```

3] Now the animation data is obtained from pose_bone.matrix as follows:

```
bone_matrix = pose_bone.matrix
if pose_bone.parent:
    bone_matrix = pose_bone.parent.matrix.inverted() * pose_bone.matrix
```

This code works fine for me.

Comment: `bone.matrix_local.inverted() *   bone.matrix_local` should always return an identity matrix...

Comment: i assume he meant to type `bone.parent.matrix_local.inverted()`